# Select arrays based on values - PHP

Tags: php, arrays

The code is in php. I have many arrays like

```
Array ( [0] => HLA-A11 [1] => HLA-class II )
Array ( [0] => HLA-class II [1] => HLA-class I )
Array ( [0] => HLA-class II [1] => HLA-A14 )
Array ( [0] => HLA-A2 [1] => HLA-A24 )
Array ( [0] => HLA-class I )
```

I would like to select the arrays that do not contain the value (HLA-class II or HLA-class I) or contain one or both but with other values (different from HLA-class I and HLA-class II). Here I would select arrays number 1,3,4. Basically I want to discard arrays that only contain HLA-class I or HLA-class II or both.

I've been using something like, $mhc_res_pos is the array with the values to compare and $final_data is the array used to store the selected alleles

```
if(in_array('HLA-class II',$mhc_res_pos)){

}
else{
    array_push($final_data, $mhc_res_pos);
}
```

Thank you

Comment: *Thank you* ? We won't write your code! Show us your attempts and we will help you to fix your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `array_filter` to do that easily.

```
$arrayTmp = array_filter($array, function ($value) {
    if ($value == 'Remove this' || $value == 'Remove that') 
        return false;
    return true;
});

if (empty($arrayTmp)) {
    // Discard $array
} else {
    // Keep $array
}
```

Not sure what you mean by "discard arrays" though.